# Bootstrap - when use rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-2

I could do

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"><h1>Title</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">content</div>
<div class="col-md-6">content</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">content</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"><p>Some Text</p></div>
</div>

...
```

or

```
<div class="row">
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="col-md-6">content</div>
<div class="col-md-6">content</div>
<div class="col-md-12">content</div>
<p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

It would both result in the same output. When do I need to use rows? It it just "ugly" or for any reason wrong and not recommended?

Comment: Both don't show the same output: https://www.bootply.com/q4a9pOdgZ4 If you can see the content has negative margins in the second output. As mentioned in the [`doc`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/): `Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins. This way, all the content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side.`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960679/what-is-the-purpose-of-row-in-bootstrap)

Comment: But can I stack multiple COLs in one row or do I need to open a new row each time the sum is 12. Because it also works to stack let's say 4 col-md-12 in one row and they are displayed below each other like it should be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the `row` div around the `col-6` columns. The other items (e.g the h1) will all go full width (if they are outside the `row` div), so no need for the `col-md-12` div.

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">content</div>
</div>
<div>content</div>
<p>Some Text</p>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. This in combination with the comment and bootply link provided by @Manoj makes sense.